# Java 8 list processing - add elements conditionally

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

I have the following piece of code:

```
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.addAll(method1());
if(list.isEmpty()) { list.addAll(method2()); }
if(list.isEmpty()) { list.addAll(method3()); }
if(list.isEmpty()) { list.addAll(method4()); }
if(list.isEmpty()) { list.addAll(method5()); }
if(list.isEmpty()) { list.addAll(method6()); }
return list;
```

Is there a nice way to add elements conditionally, maybe using stream operations? I would like to add elements from method2 only if the list is empty otherwise return and so on.

Edit: It's worth to mention that the methods contain heavy logic so need to be prevented from execution.

Comment: What do the methods return as object, exactly?

Answer (score 69):

You could try to check the return value of `addAll`. It will return `true` whenever the list has been modified, so try this:

```
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
// ret unused, otherwise it doesn't compile
boolean ret = list.addAll(method1())
    || list.addAll(method2()) 
    || list.addAll(method3())
    || list.addAll(method4())
    || list.addAll(method5())
    || list.addAll(method6());
return list;
```

Because of lazy evaluation, the first `addAll` operation that added at least one element will prevent the rest from bein called. I like the fact that "||" expresses the intent quite well.

Comment: one of the rare cases where one cares about the return value of `addAll`. indeed very clever, efficient and readable! ;-).

Comment: Agreed. I believe it can't get simpler or more readable than this.

Comment: @Aomine I don't find the misuse of boolean expressions to mimic ordered executions readable and maintainable at all. The next best bloke might reorder the expressions because "it's an OR expression, the order shouldn't matter" and boom you have a hard to find bug. The necessary comment about having a variable just for it to compile imho is a hint of bad design as well. So while this answers the question somehow, I wouldn't recommend to use this in production code.

Comment: @Darkwing I was more of comparing this against the other existing solutions, but  yes agreed to some extent.

Comment: @Darkwing Of course, the order in a boolean expression matters on an OR expression. Even the names of `method1`, ...,`method6` indicate that they **must** be executed in exactly that order. Everyone who is "reordering" code without an actual reason should be aware of that. Of course you should also add comments, which I omitted for readability.

Comment: @DorianGray The methods hopefully won't be named method1...method6 in the code! That says nothing about what they do. And yes pragmatically there is a difference in the order, but logically it does not matter. This is why you should be really careful when assuming the execution order just because you know how your compiler/jvm will translate/execute the expression. If you are optimising down to the last bit, sure order it the way it makes most sense, but don't have business logic rely on it unless there is a really big benefit/demand to do so.

Comment: @DorianGray And the lack of comments is not my problem, that there are comments necessary is my problem.

Comment: @Darkwing It's not compiler/jvm specific behaviour, language specification itsself defines that behaviour of lazy evaluation. I'm not **assuming** anything, I **know** how the language is defined. The behaviour is widely known, e.g. lazy evaluation used in order to place a null check in the first place, dereferencing it afterwards.

At least you have a very strange definition of **assuming** something that is defined in the language specification. The word **assuming** implies a certain uncertainity about the actual behaviour. If you know for sure what you are doing, you don't assume it.

Comment: @Darkwing And if the methods won't be named method1...method6 in the code, how is the reader supposed to know their order of execution? This is the point where the comments you dislike come into the code in the first place. I didn't create the dependency of execution in the first place, I came up with a nice and clean way around that, don't blame me for that.

Comment: @DorianGray I know the execution order, but I care about the logical concept of an OR statement. And that's what you first see when you look at it. You might be aware of the order, but even people who in principle know might assume the content of an OR statement to be re-arrangeable as that's what OR statements are for, to evaluate to true iff one of it's sub-expressions are true, the rest is implementation detail. Exactly my point, there are comments necessary for a small bit of code to make readers understand its behaviour and its semantics. That's a code smell.

Comment: The point is that the code smell was already there, I did not bring that up, I was proposing a nice way around a big smell. If people assume that the order doesn't matter here, it's like removing a null check and complaining about NullPointerExceptions to the original author afterwards.

Comment: @Darkwing but... the order of OR does matter! A logical OR is a short-circuit operation and is used extensively exactly because of that.

Comment: this is the only solution here I would go with, an extremely rare case where `addAll` result actually matters. beautifully done, sir!

Comment: Otherwise it won't compile.  It can be used to handle the case where no method returned any element.

Comment: @DorianGray Oh, indeed! There are only [very few expressions that can occur in statement position](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/expressions.html). That's truly mysterious. (+1)

Comment: @Darkwing Anyone who reorders an `||` thinking that the ordering doesn't matter  introducing a bug, should be told to go back and read up upon the language before doing that or similar again.  How can you even suggest such a thing?  Would YOU do that?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Sure, that could happen. I like artsy code trickery like the next best code monkey, but I recognize that people are human and such artful ways to use implementation details come with a certain risk that people overlook the details. I expect such things at low-level code optimised to the last bit, but not in everyday business code. Normally and especially if there are indications that the order matters I'd look carefully before changing something, but yes, something might slip through, especially if I'm not concerned with the business logic, say at a merge conflict.

Comment: @Darkwing That way of thinking concerns me. Hopefully you and your colleagues have good unit tests in place to catch changes in behavior.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen At the very least it likely means I have to spend more time thinking this through if I first consider the clauses equivalent and then discover that the order matters.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I'm more concerned with the opposite way of thinking, that doesn't even acknowledge a greater risk. Either way, you obviously need unit tests. And sure, I'm not saying change something whenever you want, but at some point someone will touch the code and way more often will need to understand it. For me this is generally less readable on first sight to many developers than many of the other solutions, thus wasting time.

Comment: @Darkwing The Java language provides a certain set of tools and as a developer you can expect to see them all over time.  Your mindset would never have started to use lambda expressions or generics.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen ?? No idea how you get to that, I'm not discouraging using (new) tech. Sure go ahead and use any new tech, but in line with the concepts they introduce to the langauge and where that clearly makes sense. Not every shiny new tech makes sense in every place though and if it comes with special implementation details I'd discourage to rely on those unless there is good reason for it.

Comment: @Darkwing The point is that this lazy evaluation is not a **special implementation detail**, it is a **specification detail**, that's a difference you don't seem to be aware of. Maybe this is where your aversion comes from? JLS clearly defines the difference between the boolean operators `|` and `||`, it is not up to the implementors to declare that behaviour.

Comment: @DorianGray Well, I look at boolean expressions primarily independent of the language, and in most places where I see || it could as well be | as it's used just like an abstract OR would, i.e. not in a conditional sense. I get the coder beauty of the solution, but it uses a full set of tools, i.e. the exact behaviour of || and the return value of addAll, that imho most - at least many - developers don't know by heart* and either might overlook or need to look up. So from a readability perspective I'd prefer a more explicit solution - again unless there is a specific focus on optimisation.

Comment: @DorianGray *or would not assume to be used on first sight in such a clause. But generally, I find any (perhaps most?) use of the || specification that uses it to replace a business logic representing if - then clause a readability smell. To me the conditional OR mainly makes sense as a performance optimisation tool, where you don't want to evaluate all sub-expressions when one already failed, and certainly not as a tool to design your program flow with, but we might have to agree to disagree on that.

Comment: Well, we disagree about that solution, my point in my last comment was just that you shouldn't call that behaviour an ***implementation*** detail, as it implies that this detail is up to the ***implementation*** of the java compiler. That's not the case here, as it is specified in the java language ***specification***. I just wanted to clearify that.

Comment: And the reason to use || is in the most cases not performance, but rather placing a null check before the actual check.

Answer (score 45):

I would simply use a stream of suppliers and filter on `List.isEmpty`:

```
Stream.<Supplier<List<Object>>>of(() -> method1(), 
                                  () -> method2(), 
                                  () -> method3(), 
                                  () -> method4(), 
                                  () -> method5(), 
                                  () -> method6())
    .map(Supplier<List<Object>>::get)
    .filter(l -> !l.isEmpty())
    .findFirst()
    .ifPresent(list::addAll);

return list;
```

`findFirst()` will prevent unnecessary calls to `methodN()` when the first non-empty list is returned by one of the methods.

***EDIT:***
As remarked in comments below, if your `list` object is not initialized with anything else, then it makes sense to just return the result of the stream directly:

```
return  Stream.<Supplier<List<Object>>>of(() -> method1(), 
                                          () -> method2(), 
                                          () -> method3(), 
                                          () -> method4(), 
                                          () -> method5(), 
                                          () -> method6())
    .map(Supplier<List<Object>>::get)
    .filter(l -> !l.isEmpty())
    .findFirst()
    .orElseGet(ArrayList::new);
```

Comment: Worth to note that, if `methodX()` returns a `List` and not another type of `Collection`, it might be possible to return that list directly, instead of creating a new list and adding to that: `.map(Supplier::get).filter(s -> !s.isEmpty()).findFirst().orElse(emptyList());`. Whether this is appropriate or not is not possible to determine from the question.

Comment: By the way, do you know why you have to explicitly state the type `<Supplier<List<Object>>>` to the factory method because the compiler cannot infer the type itself? I had the same issue.

Comment: @Ricola Without defining it explicitly, the compiler doesn't know the target type of lambda expressions. The alternative would have been to do it in two steps, explicitly declaring a `Stream<Supplier<List<Object>>>` as the type of the stream.

Comment: You can also use `this::method1` to reduce ther amount of boilerplate

Comment: @BoristheSpider Agreed (just didn't want to assume that the code is in an instance method)

Comment: I’m all for using functional code and in a language like Scala where it’s clean I would do it all the time, but in terms of readability I would opt for the code in the question instead. Definitely if the list of functions isn’t dynamically generated.

Comment: @SebastiaanvandenBroek Understandable. As others have mentioned, this certainly ends up being a matter of taste.

Comment: @SebastiaanvandenBroek certainly a matter of taste - I can't agree with your assessment. The code in the question has the same logic copy/pasted 5 times. The code above has no such repetition - to me this makes the functional logic rather superior.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Yes, but you could also avoid the repetition by writing a conventional for loop or while loop with a list of suppliers, and break as soon as you get something. Streams may just be obscuring things here.

Answer (score 18):

A way of doing it without repeating yourself is to extract a method doing it for you:

```
private void addIfEmpty(List<Object> targetList, Supplier<Collection<?>> supplier) {
    if (targetList.isEmpty()) {
        targetList.addAll(supplier.get());
    }
}
```

And then

```
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
addIfEmpty(list, this::method1);
addIfEmpty(list, this::method2);
addIfEmpty(list, this::method3);
addIfEmpty(list, this::method4);
addIfEmpty(list, this::method5);
addIfEmpty(list, this::method6);
return list;
```

Or even use a for loop:

```
List<Supplier<Collection<?>>> suppliers = Arrays.asList(this::method1, this::method2, ...);
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
suppliers.forEach(supplier -> this.addIfEmpty(list, supplier));
```

Now DRY is not the most important aspect. If you think your original code is easier to read and understand, then keep it like that.

Comment: You should rather name the method `addIfEmpty` instead of `addIfNotEmpty`

Answer (score 12):

You could make your code nicer by creating the method

```
public void addAllIfEmpty(List<Object> list, Supplier<List<Object>> method){
    if(list.isEmpty()){
        list.addAll(method.get());
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like this (I assumed your methods are not static methods, if they are you need to reference them using `ClassName::method1`)

```
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.addAll(method1());
addAllIfEmpty(list, this::method2);
addAllIfEmpty(list, this::method3);
addAllIfEmpty(list, this::method4);
addAllIfEmpty(list, this::method5);
addAllIfEmpty(list, this::method6);
return list;
```

---

If you really want to use a Stream, you could do this

```
 Stream.<Supplier<List<Object>>>of(this::method1, this::method2, this::method3, this::method4, this::method5, this::method6)
                .collect(ArrayList::new, this::addAllIfEmpty, ArrayList::addAll);
```

<sub>IMO it makes it more complicated, depending on how your methods are referenced, it might be better to use a loop</sub>

Answer (score 6):

You could create a method as such:

```
public static List<Object> lazyVersion(Supplier<List<Object>>... suppliers){
      return Arrays.stream(suppliers)
                .map(Supplier::get)
                .filter(s -> !s.isEmpty()) // or .filter(Predicate.not(List::isEmpty)) as of JDK11
                .findFirst()
                .orElseGet(Collections::emptyList);
}
```

and then call it as follows:

```
lazyVersion(() -> method1(),
            () -> method2(),
            () -> method3(),
            () -> method4(),
            () -> method5(),
            () -> method6());
```

method name for illustration purposes only.